# TeamExplorer in Visual Studio 2019: Page Not Found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, tfs-workitem, team-explorer

On a new PC I installed Visual Studio 2019 and everything work nicely. But after installing GitHub Extension for Visual Studio I see this error in team explorer after picking work items:
[image]

This error stays after rebooting my machine, starting visual studio as administrator and uninstalling/installing GitHub Extension for Visual Studio.

[Please click here here for version numbers of all used components.](https://gist.github.com/ezeh2/f78106e5849665837b9b10b35903062e)

I was  searching the internet for a solution. Please see below what I tried so far to fix the issue. None of these could fix my issue:

- Start Visual Studio 2019 as Administrator.
- Start *"Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019"* as administrator and enter `devenv.exe /setup`
- In Control Panel right clicked *"Visual Studio 2019"* and chose *"Change"*. Then I repaired my Visual Studio 2019 installation.
- terminate Visual Studio and rename this directory to something else and restart visual studio 2019:
  `C:\Users\myuseruname\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_7db0a03b\ComponentModelCache` After starting visual studio 2019 the above directory with new content is newly created, but the issue stays.
- In Visual Studio 2019 in Menü Extensions/ManageExtension disable all extensions and disable roaming for all extensions.
- start *"Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019"* as administrator and enter `devenv.exe /Log c:\temp\vs2019.xml`. Then Observe content of vs2019.xml in powershell with command `get-content c:\temp\vs2019.xml -tail 100 -wait`. But no additional entries are added to logfile `c:\temp\vs2019.xml` when I change in Team Explorer to workitem and the error page not found is shown.
- to solve issues with potentially corrupted data in user profile I decided to started Visual Studio 2019 with a new user profile. For this I started "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019" as administrator and entered `devenv.exe /devenv.exe /rootsuffix profile2`

After trying all the above steps the issue remained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! The issue only disappears if all these steps are done together:

- Close all instances of VS
- Delete all files in `C:\Users\myuseruname\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`
- Start *"Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019"* as administrator and enter `devenv.exe /setup`

Comment: Since you have a workaround, I suggest you could mark your own answer:)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This issue occurred with a newly installed visual studio 2019 on a new Windows 10 machine! And I only installed the `GitHub Extension`. Even though I could make it work my `\ComponentModelCache\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.err` still contains a lot `expected exactly 1 export matching constraints:`. Do you have an idea where this errors come from ? What do I need to do get rid of them ?